# Multiple file upload not saving each path in database

Tags: php, file-upload, doctrine, symfony

I have `ActivityFile` Entity which should handle files:

```
class ActivityFile {

    // all properties / setters / getters and so on

    public function upload()
    {
        foreach($this->uploadedFiles as $uploadedFile) {

            $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

            $uploadedFile->move(
                $this->getUploadRootDir(),
                $fileName
            );

            $this->path = $fileName;
            $this->name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

            $this->setRealPath($this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $fileName);

            $this->file = null;
        }
    }
```

That works fine. I'll get all uploaded files in the desired folder.

Problem is, I don't get the data in Database. Because of my Controller:

```
    class DashboardController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction(Request $request)
        {
            $activityFile = new ActivityFile();
            $activityFile->setUser($this->getUser());

            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($activityFile)
                ->add('uploadedFiles', FileType::class, array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'data_class' => null,
                ))
                ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Upload'))
                ->getForm();

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                // here is PROBLEM
                // $activityFile only contains the last file
                // from selected upload files

                $activityFile->upload();

                $em->persist($activityFile);


                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dashboard'));
            }

            return $this->render('ACMEBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(), 'activityFile' => $activityFile
            ));
        }
    }
```

How can I do the Database Entry for each uploaded file?

Answer (score 2):

You're moving all uploaded files to destination directory but the result of this operation is being stored in a property that is not an array but string. You just simply override it every time.

```
$this->path = $fileName;
```

Change the structure of your ActivityFile to store list of files not only one.

Otherwise create multiple ActivityFiles for every uploaded file using collection form type http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question. Anyway I'll try the collection next. I didn't know about that till now and will give it a try.

Comment: You're creating ActivityFile from controller and calling method "upload" on it which also creates instances of ActivityFile but they're not registered to EntityManager at all. Doctrine has no idea about their existence.
You should create them on controller level manually or use collection type.

I assume the ActivityFile should store exactly one file (not multiple ones).
Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: You are right. I did it first for one file and now I wanted to do it for multiple files. But collection looks like a lot of work.. `Doctrine has no idea about their existence` that makes sense to me. but still I have no idea how to get around it

Comment: How can I register those instances to EntityManager or can I create them on controller level?

Comment: A form for something else, means I have to create another entity to create a form for it?

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/wookieb/4bf7bb435033bde0edf1
But for practice purposes i suggest you to try collection.

Comment: tryed to implement your code but getting error: created a gist with almost all files so you can may give me further advice .. https://gist.github.com/carambazza/2bb921453aa1a6128c72

Comment: "createFromUploadedFile" should create a new instance of ActivityFile, perform upload and returns the created object. I'm sorry for not mentioning that, thought it's clear from the code.

Comment: hmm, and what is this: `new \stdClass()`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php In other words it's a very simple empty class. Might be used for forms as well :)